# Apostrophe in matcher spacy

Tags: python, text, spacy, string-matching

I am trying to detect some words using the `matcher` of `spacy`. The problem is that I can't detect words having an apostrophe `'` using `IS_PUNCT: True` in the matcher. I would like to detect the word `doctor's` in the sentence below. Here is some reproducible code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [
    [{"LOWER": "doctor"}, {"IS_PUNCT": True}, {"LOWER": "s"}]
]
matcher.add("doctor", pattern)

doc = nlp("She's on her way to the doctor's")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  
    span = doc[start:end] 
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

This won't return any output. I also tried it without `"LOWER": "s"`, but this also doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to deal with apostrophes in matching with spacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern looks for a three-token sequence, which assumes the apostrophe is its own token. But SpaCy actually tokenizes `doctor's` to the two-token sequence `["doctor", "'s"]`.

So a two-token search pattern like this will work:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [
    [{"LOWER": "doctor"}, {"LOWER": "'s"}]
]
matcher.add("doctor", pattern)

doc = nlp("She's on her way to the doctor's")
print([w.text for w in doc])
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  
    span = doc[start:end] 
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

Output:

```
['She', "'s", 'on', 'her', 'way', 'to', 'the', 'doctor', "'s"]
18058202148154971361 doctor 7 9 doctor's
```